# Not able to register webhook via postman in twitter app

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, webhooks, twitter4j

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/prod/webhooks.json?url=https://test.com not working

[image]I have followed all steps to create a new application and getting consumer key, secret keys and also token details and try to create webhook via postman. I am getting follwing error

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 32,
            "message": "Could not authenticate you."
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried delete and get methods for webhook and it is working fine.

Comment: Does that URL parameter need to be [encoded](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/guides/percent-encoding-parameters)

Comment: Experiencing the same issue with Postman. I have resorted to using the Twitter sample scripts to register web hooks. [https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard](https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard)

Answer (score 6):

They probably goofed in their example. You just need to move the `url` parameter from the query string to the form data. Use the `x-www-form-urlencoded` body.

Also - if you leave the `nonce` and `timestamp` blank, then Postman will auto-generate them for you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqR6q.png)