# Can not register twitter webhook. {“errors”:[{“code”:32,”message”:”Could not authenticate you.”}]}

Tags: twitter, webhooks, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I am trying to register a endpoint for twitter webhook but it returns
`{“errors”:[{“code”:32,“message”:“Could not authenticate you.”}]}`

I am using [twitter sample request](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/accounts-and-users/subscribe-account-activity/api-reference/aaa-premium#post-account-activity-all-env-name-webhooks) to register webhook. Here is my curl request,
[curl request to register url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E84bA.png)

`curl --request POST --url "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/:ENV_NAME/webhooks.json?https%3A%2F%2Fd216d0d30d8f.ngrok.io%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Fwebhooks%2Ftwitter" --header "authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_KEY", oauth_nonce="EhOhXekPMpf", oauth_signature="GvOx3V91BrfWuBuPKUuftYgRgHY%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1597823037", oauth_token="ACCESS_TOKEN", oauth_version="1.0""`

My endpoint is running on https using ngrok tunnel
[endpoint running on https using ngrok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF318.png)

I have got all requirements from twitter:

- Approved developer account.
- Environment setup on Account Activity API.
- Valid Consumer Key and Secret.
- Valid Access Token and Token Secret.

I have tried request using angular and https mydomain.

```js
//function to register twitter webhook 
registerTwitterWebhook() {

    // authorization in headers
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="CONSUMER_KEY",oauth_nonce="UAkSZPWDfmM",oauth_signature="%2FWSSbq4R1eTbGF4X9xg1T1e9sY4%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1597728768",oauth_token="ACCESS_TOKEN",oauth_version="1.0"',
      'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       })
    const url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account_activity/all/:ENV_NAME/webhooks.json?url="https%3A%2F%mydomain.com%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Fwebhooks%2Ftwitter"';
    return this.http.post(url, {}, { headers: headers });
}
```

On sending POST request it shows error as follows
[Error chrome web console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSZfF.png)

Kindly guide me with the possible solution for registering twitter webhook.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you’re trying to run from the browser will not work, because Twitter does not support CORS (that’s what the error message is telling you). The curl command needs to use form data for the URL submission per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57973994/262478)